# Why can't i return a value from fetch in javascript?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch

I need to get information from an api and then call for that information in another page. This is my code, here i wourld look for the information in the api:

[image]

And here i would call for it (it's in another file):

[image]

I know that fetch is asynchronous but i dont understand it at all, i need to get that information somehow there. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The problem here is that fetch is asynchronous, not synchronous. You should either turn the funnction async and wait for the response, or send a callback function as a param for the `buscaAutors` function

Answer (score 1):

As `buscarAutors` is async, when you call it as a sync function, it does not way to the fecth result to get the value.

You should `await` the call to the function an return the fetch (as a promise) in the function.